# Why keep two pillars when one pillar can do the job?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics, statics

**Question:**

A uniform plank $AB$ of $4m$ length and $15kg-wt$ weight rests horizontally on two supports/pillars: one at $A$ and the other at a point $0.5m$ from $B$. Find the weight of a boy if he can stand on top of the plank at point B without upsetting the stability of the plank.

**My book's attempt:**

[image]

Let $O$ be the middle point of $AB$ so that the weight $15 kg-wt$ acts at $O$. Let the other support be at $C$ and $Wkg-wt$ be the weight of the boy.

$$\text{So, } AB=4m,\ AO=OB=2m,\ BC=0.5m$$

According to the question, the force acting at $C$ and the resultant of $15kg-wt$ acting at $O$ and $Wkg-wt$ acting at $B$ must be equal and act in opposite directions along the same line of action.

$$\frac{15}{BC}=\frac{W}{OC}=\frac{15+W}{OB}$$

$$\text{Each force is proportional to the distance between the points of application of the other two.}$$

From the 1st and 2nd ratios,

$$\frac{15}{BC}=\frac{W}{OC}$$

$$15\cdot OC=W\cdot BC$$

$$15\cdot (2-0.5)=W\cdot 0.5$$

$$W=45$$

Desired weight of the boy is $45 kg-wt\ \text{(Ans.)}$

**My comments:**

Notice that in the book's attempt, it didn't even acknowledge the existence of the pillar/support at $A$. The book didn't consider any force coming out of $A$. It's as if the pillar/support at $A$ didn't even exist. Why then does the question give us the pillar at $A$ anyways? From common sense I think that the plank would become unstable if the support from $A$ was removed; however, I don't know if I can trust my common sense. Is the support at $A$ necessary for the stability of the plank? If yes, then why didn't the book consider any force coming out of $A$?

**My question:**

1. Is the support at $A$ necessary for the stability of the plank? If yes, then why didn't the book consider any force coming out of $A$?

Comment: If the book is considering the maximum weight possible,then you can visualize that at the maximum weight the plank will be at the verge of losing contact with pillar at A ,thus the normal is considered to be negligible.

Comment: @RamanujanXV Yes sir, the book is (most probably) considering the maximum weight possible. I tried a lot to think about how the forces are going to cancel each other out so that the normal force at $A$ is zero, but I couldn't reach a satisfactory conclusion. It'd be incredibly helpful for me if you could expand this comment into a full-fledged answer, and explain a bit as to how the forces are getting added (or subtracted).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar post on [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/698867/260477)

Comment: Please don't call me Sir, you can call me your friend I am just a 12th-grader in your neighbouring country India.I wasn't able to give full-fleged answer completely as my pre-boards are going on,thus I try to give hints in comments.

Comment: @RamanujanXV Wow! I didn't know that you are close to my age! By the way, how did you know I'm from Bangladesh?

Comment: From you question on law.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_A$ be the reaction force at point $A.$ Then, by the principle of moments, $$R_A\times AC+W\times BC=15\times OC.$$ Therefore, minimising $R_A$ maximises $W$ (noting that all the other quantities are constant); in other words, $W$ is maximum when $R_A$ is zero.